# Why does laravel5.3 5.4 doc examples all use facade fully qualified class name instead of aliases?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I learned laravel 5.2 before. Laravel 5.2 doc examples use facade class aliases. But when I start to learn laravel 5.4, I found all examples in doc use fully qualified class name instead of aliases. Why? I think using aliases is a lot easier.

Comment: Maybe because sometimes you have 2 types of Request or because people who folllow the tutorial are new and easily forget to include the classes?

Comment: Can you give an example from the docs? When it is confusing to you? you can always do a pull-request on the docs. Everybody can contribute.

Comment: You can still use Facades. You'd have to ask whoever wrote that part of the documentation to find out why they used that option over the other though.